# How can I solve "error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _Main" in visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, user-interface, visual-c++

I'm trying to make a gui program with visual studio using c++ 
and I got "error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _Main"

Error lines

: MSIL module encountered; incremental linking is disabled for MSIL; performing full link

1>LINK : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _Main

Comment: `_Main` is is not standard `c++` is it `c++-cli`?

Comment: The error message should also say which function refers to this symbol. This should be a hint to the cause of the problem.

Comment: Sure you did use the correct project template?

Comment: Are you using MFC for the GUI?